# Jsoup.Element.text() not correctly encoding utf-8

Tags: java, utf-8, jsoup

I am doing my project in eclipse, JDK 1.8.
My client recently add a new request to enable the saving and retrieval in Arabic letters too. I am have added `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`
in jdbc url. Now saving the data works correctly and I am getting the response in UTF-8 encoded form. it is working fine. for that I have added

`path = "/v2",consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"`

In all my controllers. I have an Api to generate labels in which I am using jsoup to edit html template. And then converting to pdf using wkhtmltopdf library. This fuction is working correctly if iam using english,

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(template, "UTF-8", "");
Element customerName = doc.getElementById("name");
customerName.text(orderAddress.getName());
```

if `orderAddress.getName()`
is in Arabic I am getting `?????` I just tried to print in console is also getting the same.`logger.debug("Name:"+orderAddress.getName());`
Eclipse is enabled to use utf-8.
I also tried to use like this

```
customerName.text(new String(orderAddress.getName().getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
logger.debug("Name:"+new String(orderAddress.getName().getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
```

also getting same.
in my unit testing I tried to use like this  `customerName.text("فاسيلة");`working correctly. and generating pdf exactly what I needed.

I have seen few questions similar to this but not none of them solved my issue. Since GET is working fine , I am sure about retrieving data from DB is not an issue. Since unit testing working fine encoding in that end also working fine. Now i am missing something related to jsoup.
What is I am missing in my attempt?
Some one know please help me.

Comment: Jsoup.parse(template, "ISO-8859-9", ""); notes on ISO-8859-9: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9

Comment: @AndersSørensen Thank you for your quick replay. it is worked for me

Comment: But still i have doubt why "UTF-8" not working

Comment: UTF-8 is not always supported, in the link i posted, it says most is covered by UTF-8 of the web, but there are language witch is not supported and then you need to be more specific about what language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used used UTF-8 wile writing the string to outpuut and solved

`FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempHTML, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8");`

No need to change the encoding to `"ISO-8859-9"`
keep as  `Jsoup.parse(template, "UTF-8", "");`

Comment: Nice to see you found an solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Change UTF-8 with ISO-8859-9

```
 Jsoup.parse(template, "ISO-8859-9", "");
```

Most cases UTF-8 covers the language, but some language are not supported in UTF-8

notes on ISO-8859-9: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9

Comment: is there any way to use UTF-8 itself in jsoup. That need to solve my issue?

Comment: Im not sure that will help sorry :)